# Add css classes in sequence to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with dynamic content coming from database. This div is repeat region showing about 15 records from database. This div is having a class "cslide" already assigned.

Now, I have 7 css classes namely colour1, colour2, colour3... colour7. I want to apply this classes one by one to the repeated divs in sequence like: first div will have colour1, second div will have colour2 and so on.

Can this be done using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Sure it can be done, what did you try so far, any code?

Comment: Are you averse to just using CSS's nth child and not worrying about different classes to style them?  If not I will write something up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're repeating the classes, then yes do it in jQuery like this

```
    $('.cslide').each(function(index, element)
    {
        var i = (index % 7) + 1; // 7 is the number of classes
        $(this).addClass('colour'+i);
    });
```

If this doesn't work straight in the `<script>...</script>` block, surround it in

`$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

An example of this using 5 classes and 15 objects can be seen here

https://jsfiddle.net/c5v6z8yt/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    color = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
         if(color < 7){
    color++;
    }else{
    color = 1;
    }
    $('.cslide:eq('+i+')').addClass('color'+color);
    }

});
```

```css
.color1{
    color:red
}
.color2{
    color:green
}
.color3{
    color:blue
}
.color4{
    color:yellow
}
.color5{
    color:orange
}
.color6{
    color:aqua
}
.color7{
    color:violet
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cslide"> Text1 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text2 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text3 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text4 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text5 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text6 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text7 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text1 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text2 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text3 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text4 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text5 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text6 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text7 </div>
<div class="cslide"> Text8 </div>
```

Comment: They said they had 15 elements coming from the database so this wouldn't work

Comment: Just change the for loop value based on number of elements. I have added the answer for 7 elements. Change i<=15 in for loop

Comment: Or do what I have suggested with a jQuery `.each` block to loop through each and determine the class based on the mod of the index plus 1.

Comment: Each one has a different approach

Comment: And its a variable amount coming from the database. You shouldn't hard code a length like this.

Comment: I've hardcoded 7 as thats how many classes he has, not how many objects. If he wants to add a class, he would have to add a number to the remainder calculation. If he wanted to add an object then he could without worry